# What's the difference between Set() Constructor or new Set(iterable) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm looking at this Browser Compatibility chart here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set#Browser_compatibility

[JavaScript Set Browser Compatibility][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hxdu.png

And I see that for IE11, Set() constructor is supported but not new Set(iterable). What's the difference between these two? I thought new Set(iterable) was a Set() constructor?

Comment: It looks like for the IE 11 browser we cannot perform any action that contains an array while using Set. You can notice that you can use its method to work with the single value but it will generate an error if you try to pass multiple values to it. Ref: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 1):

Probably IE's version doesn't allow argument to the constructor.

Invalid in IE:

```
const array = Array(10).fill(0).map((_, i) => i)
const set = new Set(array)
```

Valid in IE:

```
const array = Array(10).fill(0).map((_, i) => i)
const set = new Set()
array.forEach(el => set.add(el))
```

Comment: This would make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is compatible. Maybe that's a mistake?

[image]